# Multiple Father Proccesses created?

Tags: c, process

I have the following code

```
    int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ){

         printf("This is parents pid %d", getpid());
         for(int i=0;i<5;i++) // loop will run n times (n=5){ 
             if(fork() == 0) { 
                 printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid()); 
                 exit(0); 
        } 
    } 

         for(int i=0;i<5;i++) // loop will run n times (n=5) 
          wait(NULL);

}
```

And for some reason the output is the following[image]

Why it prints five times This is parent's pid??? Also when i just add a "\n" in the first print like that

```
printf("This is parents pid %d\n", getpid());
```

THE OUTPUT CHANGES TO THAT
[image]

Can anyone please explain that to me???

Comment: The `\n` you add make the text to be flush to stdout.
On your first code, the text is not flushed and each son flushes it when `\n` is written

Comment: Now run the fixed program's output through `cat` — that is, `./your-fixed-prog | cat`.  This is explained at the duplicate, as well as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) is by default (when it's connected to a terminal) *line buffered*. That means the text you print is stored temporarily in a buffer in your process. The buffer is *flushed* (actually written) either when you explicitly flush it (with `fflush`), the buffer becomes full, or when you print a newline (that's why it's called line buffered).

This buffer is copied like everything else when you fork a new child process.

What happens here is that because the `stdout` buffer isn't flushed before you fork the child processes, all the child process will start with a buffer that contains the output you print first thing in the `main` function. When the child processes prints their output, which includes the newline, all of the contents is written.

The simple solution is to add a trailing newline in the initial call to `printf`:

```
printf("This is parents pid %d\n", getpid());
//                            ^^
//   Note the newline added here
```